# Obtaining specific dates in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

I've been asked to implement a system that generates a report automatically every morning at six that takes a start and end date.  The report implementation itself is already functional, but what I'm struggling to comprehend is how to obtain the dates I need.

The end date is supposed to be the previous business day (Monday through Friday; the script will run on weekends but generate reports using the most recent Friday, and Monday's report will also use Friday as its end date).  The start date is supposed to be one year prior to the end date on the first day of that month.  We currently specify the dates manually.  I understand how to use a DateTime object to get yesterday's date, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.

How can I obtain these dates?  I know I can basically create an if statement saying to use Friday's date if the current day is a Saturday, Sunday, or Monday, but where can I go from here?  I only need the day, month, and year.  The time of day isn't important since the script records the current timestamp whenever a new report is generated.

This is what I have so far.

```
//Build the Inventory Part Report
function RunTest()
{
    //End date should be last business day
    $end_date = new DateTime();
    $end_date->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString("yesterday"));

    //Start date should be one year before end date on first day of that month
    $start_date;

    //$start_date="2014-12-01";
    //$end_date="2015-12-30";

    //Method generates report
    generateReport($start_date, $end_date);

    echo "New Report Generated Successfully!!";

}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: Could you pos some code of what you have tried as it would make it more clear to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to test the `last Friday` case, but this should do it I think:

```
$end_date;
$start_date;

if (date("w") == 0 || date("w") == 6 || date("w") == 1)
{
    $end_date = strtotime('last Friday');
}
else
{
    $end_date = strtotime("-1 day");
}

$start_date = strtotime(date("m/d/Y", $end_date)." -1 year");

echo date("m/d/Y", $start_date)." to ".date("m/d/Y", $end_date);
```

The output for today is `12/29/2014 to 12/29/2015`

If the day of week is 0, 1, or 6 (Sunday, Monday, or Saturday) we use last Friday, else we just use the previous day, and then we have our `$end_date`.  To get the `$start_date` we simply subtract one year from that.

`strtotime()` is a very useful function, and you can read more about it here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp

Comment: I'm now trying to implement this since it seems to be the most likely answer, but what exactly is "$t?"  You're using it in the top if statement and in the strtotime function inside the else statement.  I think you made one mistake though.  You say that the output is 12/29/14 to 12/29/15, but I need it to be 12/1/14 to 12/29/15.

Comment: I actually changed `$now` to `$t`

Comment: I believe you messed it up again.  You're using $t in the if statements but you're not declaring it beforehand.  It's the same problem you had in the beginning.

Comment: I'm doing too many things at once here, the `$t` wasn't even necessary since the default is `now` anyways, edited again

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it actually **did** work with the empty `$t` in there lol

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of PHP's relative dates (whoever wrote this code is a legend)

for example..

```
$date = new DateTime('first day of week');
```

This is off the top of my head and may not work.. I'll link the official [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Answer (score 0):

> where can I go from here? I only need the day, month, and year.

When you obtain your DateTime object, you simply [zero out the](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php) hours/mins/seconds.

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTime(0, 0, 0);
```

There is no difference between a Date object that represents a day and a DateTime object that represents a Date at 00:00:00 (and PHP doesn't have the former)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to making the start date the first day of the month last year.  It follows the solution I approved earlier today, and the final result winds up looking like this:

```
//End date should be last business day; Sunday, Monday, and Saturday all use the previous Friday for their end date
if(date("w") == 0 || date("w") == 6 || date("w") == 1){
    $end_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last Friday"));
}
else{
    $end_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 day"));
}

//Start date should be on eyear before end date on first day of that month
$tempStart = strtotime($end_date . " -1 year");
$start_date = date("Y-m-1", $tempStart);
```

As you can see, the last line just puts 1 in place of where "d" would go.  I've tested this and it displays the date correctly.